# registration form post field as empty

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

i'm using Yii-user, and have made some modification to the **user/views/user/registration.php** file.

for some reason even when i fill in firstname and lastname, it still says i left those fields empty. any idea why?

```
$form=$this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'registration-form',
    'type'=>'vertical',
    'enableClientValidation'=>true,
    'clientOptions'=>array(
        'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
    ),
));


<?php echo $form->textField($model,'email', array('class' => 'input-block-level', 'placeholder' => $model->getAttributeLabel('email'))); ?>

        <?php echo $form->passwordField($model,'password', array('class' => 'input-block-level', 'placeholder' => $model->getAttributeLabel('password'))); ?>

        <?php echo $form->passwordField($model,'verifyPassword', array('class' => 'input-block-level', 'placeholder' => $model->getAttributeLabel('verifyPassword'))); ?>   

        <p class="text-seperator"> about you </p>

        <?php echo $form->textField($profile,'firstname', array('class' => 'input-block-level', 'placeholder' => $model->getAttributeLabel('firstname'), 'maxlength'=> 255)); ?> 

        <?php echo $form->textField($profile,'lastname', array('class' => 'input-block-level', 'placeholder' => $model->getAttributeLabel('lastname'), 'maxlength'=> 255)); ?>
```

and in my `user/models/registrationform.php` i have this

```
    class RegistrationForm extends User {
        public $firstname; //added
        public $lastname; //added
        public $verifyPassword;
        public $verifyCode;

        public function rules() {
            $rules = array(
                array('firstname, lastname, password, verifyPassword, email', 'required'),
                array('firstname', 'length', 'max'=>225, 'min' => 3,'message' => UserModule::t("Incorrect First Name (length between 3 and 225 characters).")),
                array('lastname', 'length', 'max'=>225, 'min' => 3,'message' => UserModule::t("Incorrect Last Name (length between 3 and 225 characters).")),

.........
}
}
```

to fill up firstname and last name using the original code they used this...

```
$profileFields=Profile::getFields();
        if ($profileFields) {
            foreach($profileFields as $field) {
            ?>
    <!--div class="row"-->
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($profile,$field->varname); ?>
        <?php 
        if ($widgetEdit = $field->widgetEdit($profile)) {
            echo $widgetEdit;
        } elseif ($field->range) {
            echo $form->dropDownList($profile,$field->varname,Profile::range($field->range));
        } elseif ($field->field_type=="TEXT") {
            echo$form->textArea($profile,$field->varname,array('rows'=>6, 'cols'=>50));
        } else {
            echo $field->varname.'<br />';
            echo $form->textField($profile,$field->varname,array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>(($field->field_size)?$field->field_size:255)));
        }
         ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($profile,$field->varname); ?>
    <!--/div--> 
            <?php
            }
        }
```

Comment: It seems like you are using 2 different models $profile and $model,why is that?

Comment: the original code uses both. to read from 2 different tables

Comment: ok, but it seems like you are using just one model... maybe you should   change everything to $model ?

Comment: tried that. didnt work too. https://code.google.com/p/yii-user/downloads/list  i downloaded `yii-user-0.3-r107`

Comment: Feb 2011 is a long way back, try and var_dump the $_POST variable to see what is returning it will probably have the password but not the names inside

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change this,

you have passed `$model` in here:

```
<?php echo $form->textField($model,'email', array('class' => 'input-block-level', 'placeholder' => $model->getAttributeLabel('email'))); ?>
```

but you have given `$profile` here:

```
<?php echo $form->textField($profile,'firstname', array('class' => 'input-block-level', 'placeholder' => $model->getAttributeLabel('firstname'), 'maxlength'=> 255)); ?>
```

if you check out the **generated html**, you will notice that the generated input has **different name**!

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure why this works (would be great is someone could explain in detail)

but the issue was here..

```
public function rules() {
            $rules = array(
                array('firstname, lastname, password, verifyPassword, email', 'required'),
                array('firstname', 'length', 'max'=>225, 'min' => 3,'message' => UserModule::t("Incorrect First Name (length between 3 and 225 characters).")),
                array('lastname', 'length', 'max'=>225, 'min' => 3,'message' => UserModule::t("Incorrect Last Name (length between 3 and 225 characters).")),

.........
}
}
```

**firstname, lastname** when this is removed it works. and it still is set as required.